# Long usernames break formatting in review history

Tags: bug, design, display-names, review-history

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069707/011001000110000101110110011010) currently has a really long username. They recently reviewed many Low Quality posts, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/9203817) (example to make anyone investigating this issue's life easier), which messed up the table columns on all the pages where they had at least one review.

[image: Screenshot]

Not too sure what can be done about this except limiting username length; I suppose it's a minor issue anyway. Thought I should make people aware, though.